# Prove that if $f(z)$ is continuous on closed region then it is bounded in that region

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, continuity

While reading text on complex analysis, I found a following question:

**Question**: Prove that if $f(z)$ is continuous on closed region then it is bounded in that region.

**My attempt**: Isn't the boundedness of closed region required?

**For example** in real analysis we have example like: The function $f(x) =x$ is continuous but unbounded on the closed interval $[0, ∞)$

Further, if boundedness of the region is not required then how to prove it? Please help...

Comment: Your example is undefined at $0$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos sir I changed (edited) my example

Comment: Yes, that example works. The statement that you were supposed to prove is indeed false.

Comment: Sir, so boundedness must required? (It is necessary? )  Further is there is any example in complex analysis? The example I consider is real valued function.

Comment: The obvious $f(z) = z$ on the closed set $\mathbb C$ is an example.

Comment: Yes, boundness of the domain is required. Your your example is fine, since real numbers are complex numbers. If you wish, you can change your example a little, taking $f(x)=ix$.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer sir, thank you. Sir please can you provide a less obvious example.

Comment: why not re-use your real analysis example, i.e. the identity map but for $z = x + iy$ for $y \in \mathbb R, x \in [0, \infty)$?

Comment: Any non-constant polynomial on $\mathbb C$ works. I do not see the reason to produce more sophisticated examples because you've already proven that the question is wrong.